# Laravel caching for view

Tags: php, laravel, caching

I'm trying to optimize my application.

Is there a mechanism to cache a view partial.

```
$key = 'myUniqueKey';

if (Cache::has($key)) {
    return Cache::get($key)
}


$view = view('myview);

Cache::put($key, $view, 60);  // cache for 60 mintues

return $view;
```

Right now I'm getting an error with `Cache::put($key, $view, 60);` line because it's a closure.

Answer (score 3):

Use the `render` method on the view to get the compiled HTML:

```
return Cache::remember('my-unique-key', 60, function() {
    return view('my-view')->render();
});
```